# How to remove window's title bars?

Tags: 12.04, gtk, window-decoration

I know I can disable windows decoration via CCSM, which I currently do.

Im asking if there's way to remove title bars without losing windows decorations and/or the ability to resize with the mouse.

Thanks.

Comment: you just want to remove the name on the title bar or the WHOLE thing

Comment: THE WHOLE THING, yeah. I have no need of it, I use mostly keybindings and compiz edges bindings. And I also have a small screen, so I need that space.

Comment: check this http://jaket.is-a-geek.com/blog/linux/remove-titlebar-on-maximized-windows-with-compiz

Comment: @Ashu, like I said, that's what I already use, and not only for maximized windows. But it doesnt just remove the title bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadi was right.

So, in **metacity-theme-1.xml**, in the 2 blocks below, I added `has_title="false"` and changed some values. And voilà.

```
<frame_geometry name="frame_geometry_normal" has_title="false" title_scale="medium" rounded_top_left="true" rounded_top_right="true" rounded_bottom_left="false" rounded_bottom_right="false">
  <distance name="left_width" value="1"/>
  <distance name="right_width" value="1"/>
  <distance name="bottom_height" value="1"/>
  <distance name="left_titlebar_edge" value="1"/>
  <distance name="right_titlebar_edge" value="1"/>
  <distance name="button_width" value="0"/>
  <distance name="button_height" value="0"/>
  <distance name="title_vertical_pad" value="1"/>
  <border name="title_border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"/>
  <border name="button_border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"/>
</frame_geometry>

<frame_geometry name="geometry_maximized" has_title="false" rounded_top_left="false" rounded_top_right="false" rounded_bottom_left="false" rounded_bottom_right="false">
  <distance name="left_width" value="0"/>
  <distance name="right_width" value="0"/>
  <distance name="bottom_height" value="0"/>
  <distance name="left_titlebar_edge" value="0"/>
  <distance name="right_titlebar_edge" value="0"/>
  <distance name="button_width" value="0"/>
  <distance name="button_height" value="0"/>
  <distance name="title_vertical_pad" value="0"/>
  <border name="title_border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"/>
  <border name="button_border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"/>
</frame_geometry>
```

Comment: Where is this file located?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get rid of the titlebar, and not just the title, this looks like an unusual request which might similarly require an unusual solution, e.g try and remove title bar elements in the Window Theme you use by editing the file "metacity-theme-1.xml" and removing lines for the titlebar, buttons, etc. -- which might need some trial-and-error.

Comment: I have a feeling you're right and I don't like it ! I'll look into it and post what I did, if I don't give up before.