# Theme with thin borders?

Tags: themes

**Q1** What themes has a thin top border?

**Q2** Could I in an easy way change the size of the topborder of the default Ambiance theme

### Background

The default theme (Ambiance) which I mostly like has a top border thats 28px high which I think is wasting a lot of space on my screen if I have a bunch of windows on the same desktop.

I have tried to use MyUnity to switch theme but it does not update the themes correctly immediately and surfing for new themes on the web is also very hard since I found no good searchtool where I could see the border look in a quick way.

Comment: You could try [that](http://askubuntu.com/questions/137851/how-to-remove-windows-title-bars/164873#164873) and play with the values. You'd still have to use myunity...

Answer (score 1):

**A1** I have not found any really good ones yet. But to have an easy look at the at all the installed themes I wrote a (not so) simple oneliner:

```
locate /metacity-1/ | \
sed "s@^.*themes/\([^/]*\)/metacity-1/.*@echo \1; gconftool --type=string -s /apps/metacity/general/theme '\1'; sleep 2;@" | \
uniq | bash
```

This will show you each theme for 2 seconds and display the name of the theme in the terminal

**A2** Seems like the answer to this is *NO*. It seems like I will have to customize some existing theme to my own liking using this guide: http://blogs.gnome.org/metacity/2008/05/30/themes/