# How to get rid of titlebar?

Tags: unity, themes, gtk, titlebar

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/137851/694357) but it didn't work. I changed the file in: `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/metacity-1/metacity-theme-1.xml` and In my appearance gui window it says that I'm using Ambiance theme. How can I get rid of this useless title bar with the three buttons on it on all the windows so that for example my gnome-terminal window will look like a simple black box with an orange scroll-bar on the right side? I have never used this bar and it's just occupying my space:D! I hate it! I just don't want to see it anymore! Can anyone please help me get rid of it?

Comment: I just wish I could have a system with no gui. that I could run firefox and other applications and terminal in it. that would also show me the indicator icons as it's gui.

Comment: What's your desktop environment, Unity or GNOME? See this for GNOME: https://askubuntu.com/q/966685/480481

Comment: @pomsky I have Unity

Comment: Then please remove [GNOME] tag from the question.

Comment: @pomsky I'm sorry I didn't realize gnome was an alternative to unity I though unity was part of it! thanks.